# MongoDb RegExp on numbers in example query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The example in the node driver shows a simple regular expression used against a number.

```
collection.find({'a':/[1|2]/})
```

where collection is

```
collection.insert([{'a':1}, {'a':2}, {'b':3}]
```

This fails for me in both the shell and running the example in node.

Here is the example
https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/examples/queries.js

I wouldn't expect this to work as regular expressions are for text ... but its in the current examples ... so I figure it must be correct and I'm missing something..
The sample works fine if the values are strings {a : '1'}  ... am I missing something or is the sample out of date ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything. A $regex operation will **only** work on strings. Also from the manual

> The $regex operator provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching *strings* in queries. MongoDB uses Perl compatible regular expressions (i.e. “PCRE.”)

So the highlighted term there is "strings", and that is exactly how things **should** be.

From the source of this. It is an "odd" example, but should only be treated as an "example". So there is nothing intrinsically "wrong" with the code. It just doesn't return any results. So in that it *is arguably* still valid. No-one said it was "supposed" to match documents.

If you believe it should be otherwise, feel free to submit a pull request and or a [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa)

Comment: thanks ... its a little more than odd to me as the example crashes trying to use the returned collection length.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use regular expression with numbers, you can do it like this:

```
collection.find({ $where: "/[1|2]/.test(this.a)" })
```

But keep in mind that, [according to the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), MongoDB can't use indexes with `$where`:

> `$where` evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes. Therefore, query performance improves when you express your query using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., `$gt`, `$in`).